# Adding name creates "the object invoked has disconnected from its clients" error

Tags: vba, excel

Often, but not always, when I work on/develop in this workbook and save it manually under a new file name to increment the version number, I get
"the object invoked has disconnected from its clients" error in the line of code noted below the next time I run it:

```
Sub copy_range_names_storage_to_values(wStorage As Workbook)

Dim n As Name
For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names

    If VBA.InStr(1, n.Name, "_FilterDatabase") = 0 Then
        If VBA.InStr(1, n.Name, "_xlfn") = 0 Then
            If VBA.InStr(1, n.Name, "Values!") <> 0 Or VBA.InStr(1, n.RefersTo, "Values!") <> 0 Then
                n.Delete
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next n

Set n = Nothing
Dim sNewRefersTo As String

For Each n In wStorage.Names

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Values").Names
        If VBA.InStr(1, n.Name, "_xlfn") = 0 Then
            If VBA.InStr(1, n.RefersTo, "=" & wStorage.Sheets("Sheet1").Name & "!") > 0 Then

                sNewRefersTo = VBA.Replace(n.RefersTo, "Sheet1", "Values")
                If VBA.InStr(1, sNewRefersTo, "#REF!") = 0 Then
                    Dim rn As String
                    rn = ""
                    rn = VBA.Replace(n.Name, wStorage.Sheets("Sheet1").Name & "!", "")
                    Dim ra As String
                    ra = ""
                    ra = "=" & "Values!" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Values").Range(sNewRefersTo).Address
                     'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Values").Activate
                    .Add Name:=rn, RefersTo:=ra '<--- ERROR HERE!!!
                Else
                    n.Delete
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next n

Application.StatusBar = "copy_range_names_storage_to_values: finished"
End Sub
```

The purpose of the sub above is to delete all range names from Thisworkbook.Sheets("Values") and copy the range names from wStorage.Sheets("Sheet1") and add them to Thisworkbook.Sheets("Values"). In other words, I remove the names from Values and update them with the names on Sheet1. There are some exceptions where I don't want to copy the names over and I don't want to delete the names, etc. (as can be seen in the If statements).

One other thing to note is that it always occurs with a couple range names in particular, which happen to be the largest ranges in the workbook (2000 rows by 1250 columns and 28 rows by 1250 columns). The fact that it only occurs with the larger ranges makes me think it is a memory issue, but I would expect the error to occur more frequently/consistently if it were a memory issue because the memory usage of this pc is pretty consistent.

This is a mission critical workbook for a hedge fund client so reliability is key.

The sub has been build piece mill over time as things have come up. I am still on the hunt for a elegant way to transfer named ranges.

In concept, I understand what the error means: I have disconnected the range from the sheet or workbook somehow. But how do I avoid that or avoid the error and achieve what I need?